# How do design a 2 class+noise classifier system

Tags: multiclass-classification, noise

I need to train a 2 class classifier for a 30 x 6 frame. In the dataset, there exists data for class A and Class B, but there is a lot of junk data as well which particularly does not classify into any of the other classes, and also cannot be called a class of its own because it may just be plain noise.

please help me with some guidance for such kind of problem